# Pages and Numbers Password-Protect Feature: What Type of Encryption?

Tags: macos, security, encryption, iwork-numbers, iwork-pages

I am interested in the security of the feature mentioned in the article below:

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH23229?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US

The article mentions that encryption is used, but it is only a “note” and seems vague for such a security minded company as Apple.

My question is what type of encryption is used?  Is the file data truly encrypted or is this article just overemphasizing that a password is used.

Does this feature truly encrypt the file data or does it not encrypt the file’s data, and is it more like a login password for a Filevault-less Mac (i.e., yeah it protects against unauthorized logins, but I could just read the file's data from the hard drive data in plain text by hooking it up to a hard drive reader (no need to break the encryption because there is none).

Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Of course, they *could* be lying, but the “There’s no way to recover your password if you forget it.” statement is certainly *consistent* with the file being encrypted.